# Collision with Identity and Domain projects

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, clean-architecture

I am currently working on implementing the Clean Architecture pattern using Entity Framework. However, I've encountered an issue related to the design of my Domain project. In this project, I need to define a "Wallets" table that should have a relationship with the "User" entity from the Identity project. Additionally, the "User" entity also needs to be aware of its associated "Wallets." It's important to note that a single user can have multiple wallets, while each wallet can only belong to one user. Now, I'm uncertain about the best approach to avoid this circular dependency and where I might have made a mistake in my architecture. Any advice or insights on how to resolve this situation would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried adding some interfaces, but I ran into another issue "he property 'Wallet.User' is of an interface type ('IApplicationUser'). If it is a navigation, manually configure the relationship for this property by casting it to a mapped entity type. Otherwise, ignore the property using the [NotMapped] attribute or 'Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'"

Comment: You have separated `Context`s for each project (`Wallets` and `Users` I mean) ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You wont have direct access to the `Wallet.User` in `Wallet` project so you will have a `Wallet` class which looks like below:

```
 public class Wallet
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     ...
     // string is good abstraction for external identifier. so you have less coupling with `User` project.
     public string UserId { get; set; }
 }
```

So, I think your `Users` domain should not be aware of these `Wallets`. if it does these two domains are coupled together. and we can call them a single `Domain`.

I don't think so. You can do anything on `User.Wallets` in `Wallet` project using a single `UserId`.
You can tell him to give all of the wallets related to `UserId = 2` for example.

So, by now your `Users` project is as `abstract` as possible. it doesn't know anything about wallets and your `Wallet` project as a service should now that it has a `Owner` for each `Wallet` which is called `User`.

So, In your `User` project you have no understanding about `wallets` you can interact with `Wallet` projects:
for example:

- Create a wallet for `UserId=55` whenever I wanted (in Service layer)
  but you have no knowledge about these wallets and their insides.

In this design everything is clear. As a service `Wallet` knows what it should do. User on it's own knows how to handle `Users` business. Responsibilities are distributed in the right place.

Comment: Yeah, This is how I did it in the end. Just added UserId inside Wallet.